# Attach dynamically created variable name to $scope in controller

Tags: angularjs-scope, dynamic-variables

I am trying to create variable name dynamically and use it by attaching to $scope. 
     var val = "test";
     $scope.val = 1;

Basically i want to keep $scope variable like $scope.test = 1;

In HTML

Here variable "val" will set scope variable name dynamically. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

Use scope as an array, like this:

```
var foo = "foo";
$scope[foo] = 'Hey !'
```

And in your html:

```
{{foo}}
```

I've made an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23809/